# Adding recursively to a specific element in a matrix Maple

Tags: loops, matrix, maple

This is surely very simple to a lot of people on here but I my skills are terrible and I am struggling to add 1 to the top middle matrix element in a loop.
Here is my code:

```
 restart;
 with(LinearAlgebra):
 initialmatrix:=Matrix([[0,0,3,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1]]);

 for i from 1 to 10 do
 initialmatrix[1,3]:=initialmatrix[1,3]+1;
 end do:
```

Currently it gives "error, invalid loop" and "error, unable to parse"
Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: If I copy and paste your code I get `Matrix(5, 5, [[0, 0, 13, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])`, when calling `initialmatrix;` that is: no error message and the code seems to be working properly.

Comment: Therkel is true. There is no problem at all on your code. Sometimes, you may have to save your file, close it and reopen it. I get lot of similar issues while importing data from excel files.

Comment: Not only @Therkel is right, but I also don't see where you need `LinearAlgebra` package in this example. Even if you do not call this package, this code works fine.